# MATLAB medfilt1 without a centred filtering result

Tags: matlab, filter, median

I'm working to implement a rolling 1-D median on a 3D array. The clear choice for speed is to use the medfilt1 function. However, as the documentation indicates, this is a centred filter. From the documentation,

> Example: If n = 11, then y(k) is the median of x(k-5:k+5).
>
> Example: If n = 12, then y(k) is the median of x(k-6:k+5).

However, the behaviour I'm looking for is to find the median of x(1:k) where k is the window size. I've been toying with padding edges with nans and then omitting them at the end but with limited success. Here is some sample code:

```
%% Create test data
a  = repmat([1:1:200]',1,100);
b  = 2 .* a;
c  = 3 .* a;
d  = cat(3,a,b,c);
w  = 20;
[r,c,p] = size(d);
dummy   = nan(floor(w/2.0),c,p);
d2 = cat(1,dummy,d,dummy);

%% Apply medfilt with omitting NaNs and truncation
t1 = medfilt1(d2,w,[],1,'omitnan','truncate');

%% Check with median
t12 = t1(:,:,2);
t12(20,1)
median(b(1:20,1))

%% I assume at this point I then trim something like 'valid' here...
```

Does anyone have suggestions for a strategy to make a centred filter "behave" the way I'm looking for?

Thanks in advance!

Cheers

PS - I may not be able to reply until tomorrow evening...

Comment: You don't specify what you want to happen at the edges, so I'll just note that the `y(k)` you're looking for can be found in `y(k + floor(n/2))` from `medfilt1`.

Comment: I'd be expecting the truncation behaviour. That is, if the window has a length of 20, the value at the 10th point in one column 10 would only find the median of the first 10 observations (no zero padding). The challenge is that I'm trying to avoid a peak ahead. In other words, the last entry would be the median of the previous 19pts and itself.

Comment: Ah! I think I understand now. For a window `[1:k]`, you want the anchor to be at `k`, right? I thought you wanted it at `1`. So the first element of the filtered matrix `filtered_matrix(1,1)` will be the median of one element from the original image, `original_matrix(1,1)`. The second will be the median of `original_matrix(1,1:2)` and so on. And then the last one will be the median of one element, `original_matrix(1,end)`. Correct?

Comment: Almost. The last entry would be `original_matrix(end-k+1:end)`.I'm fooling around with flipping the matrix (fliplr or flipud) depending on the dim and shifting but just not quite getting there. For a summation, it'd be easy, use convolution with a kernel 2k-1 in length, with the values at k+1:end == 0. Done. But, the median is a tricky sort...no pun intended.

Comment: I don't know, it seems to me that padding with `n-1` NaNs and then cropping `floor(n/2)` from each side would achieve what you want, but I'm currently on Octave and the behavior isn't exactly the same as MATLAB.

Comment: No worries. Thanks for the effort though. I might just capitulate at this stage and run in a loop. If I figure something out in the meantime I'll be sure to post. Cheers!